# Angular 6 adding change event on drop down list is giving an error of undefined value

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6, onchange, event-binding

I am having a drop list generated at each row of data:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="status_change">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Change Status</th>
  <td mat-header *matCellDef="let row">
    <mat-form-field>
      <form [formGroup]="sitStatus">
        <mat-select (click)="updateUnitSituationStatus()" formControlName="sitStatusControl" placeholder="Change Status To">
          <!-- <mat-option [value]="row.unit_sprotection_status">{{row.unit_sprotection_status}}</mat-option> -->
          <mat-option *ngIf="row.unit_sprotection_status!='Active'" value="Active">Active</mat-option>
          <mat-option *ngIf="row.unit_sprotection_status!='Inactive'" value="Inactive">Inactive</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </form>
    </mat-form-field>
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

I added an event to get the value of the changed drop list. In other words, if I changed the value of drop list at row id 4, I need to get the value changed, and the id of the row, so I can update my database.

I used `(click)` event, but an error appeared:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
>       at UnitEditComponent.push

Here is the method:

```
updateUnitSituationStatus(){
    console.log(this.formGroup.controls['sitStatusControl'].value);
}
```

I tried to use `(change)` event but nothing happened too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `sitStatus` form group here `<form [formGroup]="sitStatus">` you should lookup control in that group as well

```
this.sitStatus.controls['sitStatusControl'].value
```

Comment: Okay but still no value consoled, neither on `click` nor on `change`.

Comment: Use `@Output()
selectionChange: EventEmitter<MatSelectChange>` so it will be `(selectionChange)`

Answer (score 1):

I havent tried on Material UI but I believe it works the same as normal `select`

```
<select (change)="onChangeEvent($event)">
    <option value="option1">My Options</option>
</select>
```

Then in your `.ts`

```
onChangeEvent(ev) {
    console.log(ev.target.value); // should print option1
}
```